# raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")

Tags: python, python-3.x

**new probelem with smtlib connection**

exmple

all smtp in block / close / disconect when i try send email with python with gmail or private gmail domain

**the code**

```
import pandas as pd
import smtplib

e = pd.read_excel("xxx")
emails = e['xxx'].values
server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
server.login = "xxx"
server.password = "xxx"
server.starttls()
msg = "Hello this is a email form python"
subject = "Hello world"
body = "Subject: {}\n\n{}".format(subject, msg)

for email in emails:
    server.sendmail(server.login, server.password, body)
server.quit()
```

**error**

```
  File "C:\Python39\lib\smtplib.py", line 637, in auth
    (code, resp) = self.docmd("AUTH", mechanism + " " + response)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\smtplib.py", line 427, in docmd
    return self.getreply()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\smtplib.py", line 400, in getreply
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to send mail via `smtp.gmail.com`, you need to authenticate your SMTP session. You would normally do this by calling the `login` method on the `smtplib.SMTP` object...but you've replaced this method with a string, so you can't do that even if you tried.

Because you're not authenticating, Gmail is disconnecting you.

Also, you appear to be using your username and password where the `sendmail` method expects a "from" and "to" email address.

You probably want your code to look more like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import smtplib

e = pd.read_excel("xxx")
emails = e['xxx'].values

server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
server.starttls()
server.login("your_gmail_account_here", "your_password_here")

msg = "Hello this is a email from python"
subject = "Hello world"
body = "Subject: {}\n\n{}".format(subject, msg)

for email in emails:
    server.sendmail("you@your_email_address", email, body)
server.quit()
```

This assumes that `emails` is in fact a list of email addresses. You will need to fill in information here (your username, password, and email address) before this will work correctly.